# How do biometric password managers work?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management

Many password managers for mobile offer the option to unlock the password vault with a fingerprint instead of a password. If you never type in your master password, how is it possible to decrypt the data? It appears that there must be a way to decrypt the database without actually typing in the master password.

Comment: Why do you think the master password is required to decrypt?

Comment: And I think any specific answer will be specific to a particular product. For LastPass, it is explained here: https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/lastpass-for-android-lp060001

Comment: @schroeder Because the contrary would imply that it is possible to decrypt the database without knowing the password, which would defeat the whole point of having a password.

Comment: Ah, then you have an X/Y problem. Read the LastPass link for at least one product's approach.

Comment: Password is required, it's just not required to be entered every time. Various methods to either cache the password or keep the db decrypted.